# SQL How to Select the most recent date item

Tags: sql, oracle, select, date

Hello I have a table with columns:

*using oracle

```
ID                  NUMBER
USER_ID            NUMBER
DATE_ADDED          DATE
DATE_VIEWED        DATE
DOCUMENT_ID        VARCHAR2
URL                VARCHAR2
DOCUMENT_TITLE      VARCHAR2
DOCUMENT_DATE        DATE
```

I want to know how i can get the most recently added document for a given user.

```
Select * FROM test_table WHERE user_id = value AND (do something with date_added column)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
Select * 
FROM test_table 
WHERE user_id = value 
AND date_added = (select max(date_added) 
   from test_table 
   where user_id = value)
```

Comment: If you have a lot of users, does this result in one separate select query per user, which is not performant and may time out?

Answer (score 17):

Not sure of exact syntax (you use varchar2 type which means not SQL Server hence TOP) but you can use the LIMIT keyword for MySQL:

```
Select * FROM test_table WHERE user_id = value
     ORDER BY DATE_ADDED DESC LIMIT 1
```

Or rownum in Oracle

```
 SELECT * FROM
     (Select rownum as rnum, * FROM test_table WHERE user_id = value ORDER BY DATE_ADDED DESC)
 WHERE rnum = 1
```

If DB2, I'm not sure whether it's TOP, LIMIT or rownum...

Answer (score 9):

With SQL Server try:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM dbo.youTable
WHERE user_id = 'userid'
ORDER BY date_added desc
```

Answer (score 4):

You haven't specified what the query should return if more than one document is added at the same time, so this query assumes you want all of them returned:

```
SELECT t.ID,
       t.USER_ID,
       t.DATE_ADDED,
       t.DATE_VIEWED,
       t.DOCUMENT_ID,
       t.URL,
       t.DOCUMENT_TITLE,
       t.DOCUMENT_DATE
FROM (
  SELECT test_table.*,
         RANK()
         OVER (ORDER BY DOCUMENT_DATE DESC) AS the_rank
  FROM   test_table
  WHERE  user_id = value
  )
WHERE the_rank = 1;
```

This query will only make one pass through the data.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your RDBMS know window functions and CTE and USER_ID is the patient's id:

```
WITH TT AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY USER_ID ORDER BY DOCUMENT_DATE DESC) AS N
    FROM test_table
)
SELECT *
FROM TT
WHERE N = 1;
```

I assumed you wanted to sort by DOCUMENT_DATE, you can easily change that if wanted. If your RDBMS doesn't know window functions, you'll have to do a join :

```
SELECT *
FROM test_table T1
INNER JOIN (SELECT USER_ID, MAX(DOCUMENT_DATE) AS maxDate
            FROM test_table
            GROUP BY USER_ID) T2
    ON T1.USER_ID = T2.USER_ID
        AND T1.DOCUMENT_DATE = T2.maxDate;
```

It would be good to tell us what your RDBMS is though. And this query selects the most recent date for every patient, you can add a condition for a given patient.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Top 1* FROM test_table WHERE user_id = value order by Date_Added Desc
```

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: oops.. I must have missed formatting, I didn't notice. Thanks anyway.