# Get both most recent and prior entry from database

Tags: sql, join, timestamp

This site already has a handful of questions and answers about selecting the most recent entry in from database table that has a timestamp column, for each given key.  Here is [one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090789/sql-how-to-select-the-most-recent-date-item).  I had been using code similar to this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.FooId, t1.BarId, t1.Status, t1.ChangeDate
FROM FooBarStatusUpdate t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT FooId, BarId, MAX(ChangeDate) AS latest
        FROM FooBarStatusUpdate
        GROUP BY FooId, BarId) AS t2
ON t1.FooId = t2.FooId
AND t1.BarId = t2.BarId
AND t1.ChangeDate = t2.latest
```

The table in question holds a many-to-many mapping between Foo and Bar, as well as the status of the Foo within the Bar, and the date the status changed.  There is an entry in this table for every status change, starting from when the Bar is first asssigned to the Foo.

The other day, I needed to [ask a duck](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html) about how to select not only the most recent item, but also the immediately prior entry for the same key.  In this case, it was for a report showing what has changed in the past month, and needed to show not only what it changed *to*, but also what it changed *from*.  How could I modify my query above, I asked the duck, to get the results for this report my client so urgently needs?

Well, the duck gave me what I needed, so my own answer below is here in hopes of helping the community.

**EDIT (As requested by JW):**

Suppose this is my original data:

```
FooId      BarId       Status     ChangeDate
  2          5          New       03/27/2012
  2          5          Commit    05/04/2012
  2          5          Complete  07/20/2012
  3          8          New       06/18/2012
  3          8          Commit    08/12/2012
```

Then my first query (above) will return:

```
FooId      BarId       Status     ChangeDate
  2          5          Complete  07/20/2012
  3          8          Commit    08/12/2012
```

What I want my new query to do (and what my answer in fact does) is return:

```
FooId      BarId       Status     Change Date   Prior Status
  2          5          Complete  07/20/2012      Commit
  3          8          Commit    08/12/2012      New
```

Comment: can you give sample record with your desired result? `:)` it helps the reader (*especially me*) gives more additional information on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoth the duck:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.FooId, t1.BarId, t1.Status, t1.ChangeDate,
t3.Status as formerStatus
FROM FooBarStatusUpdate t1

INNER JOIN (SELECT FooId, BarId, MAX(ChangeDate) AS latest
        FROM FooBarStatusUpdate
        GROUP BY FooId, BarId) AS t2
ON t1.FooId = t2.FooId
AND t1.BarId = t2.BarId
AND t1.ChangeDate = t2.latest

LEFT JOIN (SELECT FooId, BarId, Status, MAX(ChangeDate) AS nextlatest
        FROM FooBarStatusUpdate
        GROUP BY FooId, BarId, Status
        ) AS t3
ON t2.FooId = t3.FooId
AND t2.BarId = t3.BarId
AND DATEDIFF(DAY, nextlatest, t2.latest) > 0
```

Comment: Note that the example shows syntax for MSSQL 2008 (i.e. DATEDIFF function), but should be easily modifiable to other RDBMS.